# why set localStorage.setItem data with !0 instead of 1 or true?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I saw this and don't know if this is a preferred way to set something as true or someone is trying to just be fancy? When using localStorage.setItem, to set a value to true, !0 is being used:`localStorage.setItem("proddtm", !0);`Is this better than using a 1 or true? If so why?

Comment: Saves two characters?

Comment: probably output from uglify.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!0` is just fancy. It is **coerced to a boolean type** with the value of `true`, which is the same value as a regular `true` boolean. However, `1` is a number, but `!!1` would actually be `true`.

I would have to see the context of the actual usage, but `!0` and `true` are equivalent.

[image: output]

There are use cases for coercing a value to a boolean (for example, when checking a parameter, like `!!someParameter`, which will return true if not `null`, `undefined`, `0`, or other falsy values, but it just depends.)

One **potential** benefit would be that `true` doesn't minify any further, but `!0` saves you a couple bytes or whatever, but this is definitely some micro-optimization, as I don't see where using `true` over `!0` would ever cause a bottleneck in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is no different than using true or false other than being a bit more obfuscated and thus less desirable.